# Select row that has max total value SQL Server

Tags: sql

**I have the following scheme (2 tables):**

Customer (Id, Name) and
Sale (Id, CustomerId, Date, Sum)

**How to select the following data ?**

1) Best customer of all time (Customer, which has Max Total value in the Sum column)

For example, I have 2 tables (Customers and Sales respectively):

```
id    CustomerName      
---|--------------
1  | First         
2  | Second 
3  | Third 



id  CustomerId  datetime     Sum
---|----------|------------|-----
1  | 1        | 04/06/2013 | 50
2  | 2        | 04/06/2013 | 60
3  | 3        | 04/07/2013 | 30
4  | 1        | 03/07/2013 | 50
5  | 1        | 03/08/2013 | 50
6  | 2        | 03/08/2013 | 30
7  | 3        | 24/09/2013 | 20
```

Desired result:

```
CustomerName TotalSum
------------|--------
 First      | 150
```

2) Best customer of each month in the current year (the same as previous but for each month in the current year)

Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried.  Do you know you need to `join` the tables first.  Then you can Sum or aggregate the individual Sum and find the Max Value.  Please take some steps to show us the effort you have already taken.  Great description of the problem though.

Comment: Yes, of course I joined tables first. I do the following :
`SELECT
  Customer.Name,
  TotalSum
FROM
Customer INNER JOIN 
(SELECT 
   Sale.CustomerId,
   SUM(Sum) as TotalSum
 FROM Sale
 GROUP BY Sale.CustomerId
)temp ON Customer.Id = temp.CustomerId`

I got the result-set with two columns (CustomerName, TotalSum) and three rows (for each Customer). But how at this point to select Customer with Max TotalSum?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this for the best customer of all times

```
SELECT Top 1 WITH TIES c.CustomerName, SUM(s.SUM) AS TotalSum
FROM Customer c JOIN Sales s ON s.CustomerId = c.CustomerId
GROUP BY c.CustomerId, c.CustomerName
ORDER BY SUM(s.SUM) DESC
```

Comment: How does this calculate the `sum`?  You're summing on the customer id field?  Not so mention ordering by the `max(customerid)`... This will always return the highest customer id...

Comment: Looks better.  What about ties?  Assuming that's not an issue, this would be the easier solution.

Comment: Thanks, but what if there are several customers with the same MaxValue of TotalSum? It probably won't be correct to get only one of them.

Comment: @user2480596 thanks for the with ties, I didn't know that it existed. Learned something today :)

Comment: @Sanek if there are more than one, "top 1 with ties" do the job.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use `RANK()` combined with the `SUM` aggregate.  This will get you the overall values.

```
select customername,  sumtotal
from (
  select c.customername, 
    sum(s.sum) sumtotal,
    rank() over (order by sum(s.sum) desc) rnk
  from customer c
    join sales s on c.id = s.customerid
  group by c.id, c.customername
  ) t
where rnk = 1
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d1a7a/2)

Grouping this by month and year should be trivial at that point.